# php email script sends to some kind of emails but not to other

Tags: php, email, actionscript, smtp

I have a little php script on my server for sending mail:

```
<?
$to=$_POST["to"];
$subject=$_POST["subject"];
$body=$_POST["body"];
mail($to,$subject,$body);
?>
```

when I pass this kind of email - **myEmail@gmail.com** all is fine but when I pass this kind of mail - **mail@myWebSite.com** the mail won't send. any ideas why?

EDIT: i should mention that **mail@myWebSite.com** is actually **mail@myWebSite.co.il** although i don't think that should matter

thanx in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "the mail won't send"? Do you get an error message? A bounce message? If neither, how do you know it wasn't sent? Do you have access to local mail server logs?

Comment: I doubt it's "not sending" - more likely the mywebsite.com is trashing the email as spam. Check your SMTP server logs to see what happens after PHP hands over the email.

Comment: there is no spam filtering at mywebsite.com

Comment: I should state that I don't know if my server has any mail services. Does that matter? - since emails to gmail ARE being sent and received... also i know almost no server side code so i don't debug my php script - where do i find error/bounce? this php script is triggered by my Adobe AIR app which I wrote in AS3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue involves the fact that the same php script behaves differently on windows and linux servers.

Answer (score -1):

Try sending a richer email data. Send it from the server that hosts myWebSite.com!
And make sure the mywebsite.com has a mail server listening online ;)

[Email headers](http://www.htmlite.com/php029.php)

Edit:
Can you try this one?

```
$to=$_POST["to"];
$subject=$_POST["subject"];
$body=$_POST["body"];
$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: Sender Name <mail@yoursite.com>";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: Recipient Name <mail@yoursite.com>";
mail($to,$subject,$body, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

Comment: You don't need extra data in your e-mail.  Nor do you need to send it from a server that hosts that site.

Comment: Well, you do, if you need official email. You write from@ mail domain same as server domain and it passes most of spam filters that way.

Comment: thanx, but i also have access to myWebSite.com and i know for a fact that spam filtering is not turned on there - it must be something else

Comment: @GundarsMēness, Envelope from is handled by your sendmail configuration.  The rest isn't all that necessary depending on what you need.